# sql oracle - "Вывести фамилию и имя читателей, держащих книги более 4-х месяцев"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

```
select p_name, s_name
from reader
join card on user_id
where return_date-issue_date>4
group by p_name, s_name
```

Подсказывают, что Join написан неверно. Группировка мол в таком запросе не нужна (используется в паре с агрегатными функциями) и что если нужно, то лучше использовать distinct

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT reader.p_name, reader.s_name
FROM reader
JOIN card ON reader.user_id = card.user_id
WHERE card.return_date - card.issue_date > 4
GROUP BY reader.p_name, reader.s_name;
```

Comment: 4 месяца, а не дня... `MONTHS_BETWEEN()`

Answer (score 0):

Схема таблиц и примерное содержимое неизвестно. Насколько я понял, будет примерно так:

```
SELECT
  r.P_NAME,
  r.S_NAME
FROM
  card c
  INNER JOIN reader r ON r.User_ID = c.User_ID
WHERE
  MONTHS_BETWEEN(NVL(c.RETURN_DATE, CURRENT_DATE), c.ISSUE_DATE) < 4;
```

Как отметил [Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina) надо использовать метод `MONTH_BETWEEN(date1, date2)`, чтобы подсчитывать разницу именно по месяцам. Также следует заранее предположить, что читатель может вообще не вернуть книгу. Cоответственно, нужна замена `NULL` на текущую дату для поля `RETURN_DATE`.